# How to change a value in a column on a SQLite database?

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a SQLite database with this format:

```
TABLE users
    |
    |---------name - text
    |
    |---------avatar - text
    |
    |---------password - text
    |
    |---------userdir - text
    |
    |---------role - numeric
```

I want to change the number of `role`. How could I change it? (I mean, what query?)

I'm using PHP if anyone needs it. Thanks!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
UPDATE users SET role=99 WHERE name='Fred'
```