# How to set all values in a column to empty (null)?

Tags: sqlite

How to set all values in a column to empty (null)?. To reset the value of a nullable column for every row in a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ignore the `WHERE` clause would do the trick. [How to change a value in a column on a SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776657/how-to-change-a-value-in-a-column-on-a-sqlite-database)

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = NULL
```